# I need to create alerts based on the results returned by queries in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, alert, amazon-athena

I need to create alerts based on the results returned by queries in Amazon Athena. I don't see how I can do that now.

For example -

1. Schedule a query to be executed once an hour (I am not aware of a way to do this now)
2. Based on the results of the query (for example I would be checking the number of transactions the last hour), I might need to send an alert to someone that something may be wrong (number of transactions is too low).

I know this is different but I would do something similar, in SQL Server, using a SQL Server Agent job.

Comment: Hi @sgn. What do you mean by "alerts based the results returned by queries in Amazon Athena"? Can you tell us more about your end-to-end process? For example, how are the queries run? Are they run manually, or scheduled somehow? Are you doing something like "Every hour I want to run some queries in Amazon Athena. If the result is > 3 then I want to send a notification to some users"? Please Edit your question to provide this level of detail so that we can offer some appropriate advise.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I updated my question, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no in-built capability to run Amazon Athena queries on a schedule and send notifications. However, you could configure this using AWS services.

I would recommend:

- Create an **Amazon SNS topic** that will receive notifications

  - Subscribe recipients to the SNS topic (eg via email, SMS)
- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Event** that [triggers on a cron schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)
- Configure the Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function
- Write code for the **AWS Lambda function** to:

  - Run an **Amazon Athena query**
  - Compare the result to desired values
  - If the result is outside desired values, **send a message to the Amazon SNS Topic**